# Attempting to split and store arrays similar to strtok

Tags: c, string, strtok

For an assignment in class, we have been instructed to write a program which takes a string and a delimiter and then takes "words" and stores them in a new array of strings. i.e., the input ("my name is", " ") would return an array with elements "my" "name" "is".

Roughly, what I've attempted is to:

1. Use a separate helper called `number_of_delimeters()` to determine the size of the array of strings
2. Iterate through the initial array to find the number of elements in a given string which would be placed in the array
3. Allocate storage within my array for each string
4. Store the elements within the allocated memory

Include directives:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

This is the separate helper:

```
int number_of_delimiters (char* s, int d)
{
    int numdelim = 0;
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == d)
        {
            numdelim++;
        }
    }
    return numdelim;
}
```

`This is the function itself:

```
char** split_at (char* s, char d)
{
    int numdelim = number_of_delimiters(s, d);
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    char** final = (char**)malloc((numdelim+1) * sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i <= numdelim; i++)
    {
        int sizeofj = 0;
        while (s[a] != d)
        {
            sizeofj++;
            a++;
        }

        final[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeofj);
        a++;
        int j = 0;

        while (j < sizeofj)
        {
            final[i][j] = s[b];
            j++;
            b++;
        }

        b++;
        final[i][j+1] = '\0';
    }
    return final;
}
```

To print:

```
void print_string_array(char* a[], unsigned int alen)
{
    printf("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < alen; i++)
    {
        if (i == alen - 1)
        {
            printf("%s", a[i]);
        }
        else
        {
        printf("%s ", a[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("}");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    print_string_array(split_at("Hi, my name is none.", ' '), 5);
    return 0;
}
```

This currently returns {Hi, my name is none.}

After doing some research, I realized that the purpose of this function is either similar or identical to strtok. However, looking at the source code for this proved to be little help because it included concepts we have not yet used in class.

I know the question is vague, and the code rough to read, but what can you point to as immediately problematic with this approach to the problem?

Comment: Can you show us the `number_of_delimiters` function, how you call the `split_at` function and how you print the result?

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger to see what goes wrong. BTW: It may be a help to replace the delimiter with `'\0'`  while iterating, so you can allocate space and copy out the words easily. If you you are not allowed to do this on the source (`const`?), make a copy.

Comment: "Currently, this just returns an array of spaces." How do you check? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your first while loop emulates a `strchr(s+a, d);` ,more ore less. Your second while loop effectively does a memcpy(). Plus: you need to allocate one character more than sizeofj. And: `for (int i = 0; i < numdelim; i++){...}`

Comment: Where do you get the second parameter to pass to `print_string_array`? What is `end` in `split_at`? Note, all words are significant in [mcve]. A complete program has `main()` and `#include` directives, for example.

Comment: I've edited the question to answer some of the comments. I apologize for the issues with the question itself; I've only just begun asking questions on stack. Also, while some of my loops may be more easily done using items in the string library, we've been instructed to keep our use of string library functions to a minimum, and to instead practice accomplishing these goals with loops.

Comment: **Are you using any #include directives?**

Comment: "This currently returns {Hi, my name is none.}" What do you expect it to print?

Comment: This is not a debugging service. Please stop presenting us a moving target to fix. I am reverting your changes to the state where answers are valid. If you have additional questions, ask them separately.

Comment: Understood. Apologies.

Comment: This is a good time to learn some basic skills. Start yoir debugger. Trace rhe execution of the program step by step, noting the values of critical variables at each step. Find the harmful change you have intriduced.

Answer (score 0):

Just for explanation:

`strtok` will *modify* the array you pass in! After

```
char test[] = "a b c ";
for(char* t = test; strtok(t, " "); t = NULL);
```

`test` content will be:

```
{ 'a', 0, 'b', 0, 'c', 0, 0 }
```

You get subsequently these pointers to your test array: `test + 0`, `test + 2`, `test + 4`, `NULL`.

strtok remembers the pointer you pass to it internally (most likely, you saw a `static` variable in your source code...) so you can (and *must*) pass `NULL` the next time you call it (as long as you want to operate on the same source string).

You, in contrast, apparently want to copy the data. Fine, one can do so. But here we get a problem:

```
char** final = //...
return final;

void print_string_array(char* a[], unsigned int alen)
```

You just return the array, but you are losing length information!
How do you want to pass the length to your print function then?

```
char** tokens = split_at(...);
print_string_array(tokens, sizeof(tokens));
```

will fail, because `sizeof(tokens)` will always return the size of a pointer on your local system (most likely 8, possibly 4 on older hardware)!

My personal recommendation: create a null terminated array of c strings:

```
char** final = (char**)malloc((numdelim + 2) * sizeof(char*));
//                                        ^ (!)

// ...

final[numdelim + 1] = NULL;
```

Then your print function could look like this:

```
void print_string_array(char* a[]) // no len parameter any more!
{
    printf("{");
    if(*a)
    {
        printf("%s", *a);   // printing first element without space
        for (++a; *a; ++a)  // *a: checking, if current pointer is not NULL
        {
            printf(" %s", *a); // next elements with spaces
        }
    }
    printf("}");
}
```

No problems with length any more. Actually, this is exactly the same principle C strings use themselves (the terminating null character, remember?).

Additionally, here is a problem in your own code:

```
while (j < sizeofj)
{
    final[i][j] = s[b];
    j++; // j will always point behind your string!
    b++;
}

b++;
// thus, you need:
final[i][j] = '\0'; // no +1 !
```

For completeness (this was discovered by n.m. already, see the other answer): If there is no trailing delimiter in your source string,

```
while (s[a] != d)
```

will read beyond your input string (which is undefined behaviour and could result in your program crashing). You need to check for the terminating null character, too:

```
while(s[a] && s[a] != d)
```

Finally: how do you want to handle subsequent delimiters? Currently, you will insert empty strings into your array? Print out your strings as follows (with two delimiting symbols - I used * and + like birth and death...):

```
printf("*%s+", *a);
```

and you will see. Is this intended?

**Edit 2**: The variant with pointer arithmetic (only):

```
char** split_at (char* s, char d)
{
    int numdelim = 0;
    char* t = s; // need a copy
    while(*t)
    {
        numdelim += *t == d;
        ++t;
    }

    char** final = (char**)malloc((numdelim + 2) * sizeof(char*));
    char** f = final; // pointer to current position within final

    t = s;  // re-assign t, using s as start pointer for new strings
    while(*t) // see above
    {
        if(*t == d) // delimiter found!
        {
            // can subtract pointers --
            // as long as they point to the same array!!!
            char* n = (char*)malloc(t - s + 1); // +1: terminating null
            *f++ = n; // store in position pointer and increment it
            while(s != t) // copy the string from start to current t
                *n++ = *s++;
            *n = 0; // terminate the new string
        }
        ++t; // next character...
    }
    *f = NULL; // and finally terminate the string array
    return final;
}
```

Comment: The behavior you have described with subsequent delimiters is the expected one, according to the assignment (though I did not include that information). Taking into account the edits both you and n.m. suggested, and editing the print function you provided for newline characters rather than spaces, it currently prints: {Hi, 
(\n)y n
(\n)me is
(\n)non
(\n).}

Comment: @BrianFenaughty OK, then fine. However, you are doing stuff a little complicated, not profiting from the fact that c-strings are null terminated other than calculating your x. If you use pointer arithmetic, you can simplify your code quite a lot. If interested, I can show you for comparison...

Comment: That would be helpful, yes please

Comment: @BrianFenaughty OK, here it is. Just a side note: If you really want to profit from: Don't just copy and paste it to your homework! First try to fully understand it (ask further questions, if need be) - then try to re-implement it *yourself*.

Comment: Thank you! For the sake of honesty, I will use my own code (now that I've fixed it), but looking at this solution gives me a much better sense of how I should've looked to approach this from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The program has several problems.

1. `while (s[a] != d)` is wrong, there is no delimiter after the last word in the string.
2. `final[i][j+1] = '\0';` is wrong, `j+1` is one position too much.
3. The returned array is unusable, unless you know beforehand how many elements are there.

Comment: I've changed the code to reflect the first two points here. As far as the third, I'm not sure if there's something I can do about that within the framework of the assignment. We are sometimes given work to practice skills which may not necessarily lead to "useful" programs, in some senses.

Answer (score 0):

While I've now been shown a more elegant solution, I've found and rectified the issues in my code:

```
char** split_at (char* s, char d)
{
    int numdelim = 0;
    int x;
    for (x = 0; s[x] != '\0'; x++)
    {
        if (s[x] == d)
        {
            numdelim++;
        }
    }
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    char** final = (char**)malloc((numdelim+1) * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i <= numdelim; i++)
    {
        int sizeofj = 0;
        while ((s[a] != d) && (a < x))
        {
            sizeofj++;
            a++;
        }
        final[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeofj);
        a++;
        int j = 0;
        while (j < sizeofj)
        {
            final[i][j] = s[b];
            j++;
            b++;
        }
        final[i][j] = '\0';
        b++;
    }
    return final;
}
```

I consolidated what I previously had as a helper function, and modified some points where I incorrectly incremented .